# How to send current schema and affected table with notification function/trigger?

Tags: sql, postgresql

When a row is inserted or updated in a specific table (in this example it's the table called 'fpl'). How can I include the affected table and schema in the notification?

SQL as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER fpl_event
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON fpl
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE fpl_notify();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fpl_notify()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
NOTIFY dbNotification, 'something got insereted in fpl!';
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html `TG_TABLE_NAME` and `TG_TABLE_SCHEMA`

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fpl_notify() RETURNS trigger 
AS 
$$ 
BEGIN 
  EXECUTE format('notify dbNotification, ''%s''', TG_TABLE_SCHEMA); 
  RETURN NULL; 
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

read [trigger  special variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)

Comment: still not working.

Got this working: 
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fpl_notify()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
EXECUTE format('notify dbNotification, ''%s''', TG_TABLE_SCHEMA);
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;